# Relationship between Prarabdha Karma and Sookshma or Linga Shareera

Tags: karma, samskara

I have heard from contemporary spiritualists that Karma is actually stored in one's body, in different layers.

There are three types of Karma

1. Prarabdha Karma
2. Sanchita Karma
3. Agami Karma

Now leaving out Agami Karma which happens in future.

There are three types of bodies or Shareeras

1. Sthoola Shareera
2. Sookshma or Linga Shareera
3. Karana Shareera

---

**Now its said that

Sanchita Karma is stored in Karana Shareera and

Prarabdha Karma is stored in Sookshma Shareera.**

Can any one please give scriptural backing for this by giving appropriate verses

Comment: @GIRIBLR This is the question I was asking about

Comment: No, it is not 'stored' If it was stored, it would imply that it is insentient and that what the fruits of the karma is already determined. The Lord is the giver of the fruits, He alone determines. See Brahma Sutras 3.2.38-41; Brhadaranyaka Upanishad 4.4.24; GIta 7.21-22

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Of course he alone determines but he works it out by storing it as karma in sookshma shareera. Nobody is debating who does it. Of course God stores it. The question is how does God do it, in what procedure. When the word stored is used its simply implying the position. Like Goods are stored in Godown. It doesn't mean it was done automatically. Of course it was done by manual labour.

Comment: I didn't understand the difference between sthula and karana sharers. There is only linga, aniruddha/sukshma and sthula/current body  what is Karamazov Shareara here what I heard from keshava tadiipatri there is some amount karma stored jiva swaroopa that Chita memory shell not in any Shareara because jiva retains various levels of bliss in moksha because linga shareeea is lost in moksha  if it stored in any of the shareerA they cannot enjoy different levels bliss in moksha as all the shareera is lost

Comment: @PrasannaR this is according to Advaitic model. Please refer Tattva Bodha if you are interested. Its a short and precise book on Advaita model of the world. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://vedantastudents.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/01-Tattva-Bodha-Versewise-Notes.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjWgNWKk_bxAhWM7XMBHXm4B1cQFjAIegQIHxAC&usg=AOvVaw3_yoS4Bn_dTa1R2H2P-aeQ

Comment: @PrasannaR also please tell me what's the Dvaita Model is. 1. Swaroopa Shareera 2. Linga or Aniruddha or Sukshma 3. Sthoola. Correct right?? Also can you please give link to Keshava Tadipatri's video

Comment: no small correction 1. Atma swaroopa( which have everything in it. chita, ananda and sat. ) in chita karma is stored this is jiva. (inside every jiva Lord Paramatma resides again he is also sat chit ananda roopa)  as Per BG. 15-7 and 15-15  2. Linga sharira ever present and beginning less gets destroyed in moksha. 3.  Sukhsma Sharira /Aniruddha deha. 4. Sthula sharira.  whatever we see as outer body is gods efflugence which controls every action. the karma is stored in chita memory shell.. but my knowledge is very limited

Comment: Suppose a person born blind in this birth but he is not blind in atma swaroopa.. so he can be born with eyes in next birth.

Comment: According to madvacharya, All Karmas, Sanchita karma, prarbhda karma destroyed once with get Atma sakshatkara(i.e. seeing god in ones being) Now The Jiva becomes the observer he clearly sees gods action from inside is body that is why he losses grip of karma.. like question paper is out before the exame he knows all the answers.. so he need be part of the exam. so moksha is acheived with all sanchita karma is destroyed in that birth, but by that accound prahalad should have already attained moksha but again born as Sri Raghavendra swamigal by their own desire and gods desire.

Comment: @PrasannaR wait wait aren't Linga and Aniruddha shareera the same body?? Also are you sure there's karma stored in Jeeva Swaroopa? I don't think so.. As you'll get moksha only when there's no karma left. Chitta means consciousness, how can consciousness have karma, can you please give some reference link

Comment: @PrasannaR is there a link where information about this is given

Comment: see according Sri Madvacharya.. Jiva experience different levels of bliss based on the sadhana, if one takes sadhana as karma it should be retained in moksha. Logic is simple if it gets stored in anyother places other than chitt  or memory shell of jiva swaroopa, there is no way this difference in levels of bliss based on sadhana can be obtained.. because memory storage is lost. its like cpu -> RAM/ROM -> HDD, SDD here sat is cpu and chitta is memory shell which is consicousness which stores all levels of information..

Comment: Ananda is effect of this blisss that jiva enjoys in moksha based on the storage.. Karma is destroyed for moksha.. means all negative reaction of karma is lost.. not completely destoryed because jiva is aware of its swaroopa now jiva is aware presence of God and doer of karma now he clearly is able to see he is instrument so effect of karma is retained for the jiva

Comment: @PrasannaR I'm not questioning Madhwacharya's logic, but I humbly think you have misunderstood Madhwacharya's logic. First of all Chitta means consciousness not memory. There is a difference. Second no karma difference is necessary for explaining the difference of ananda in moksha. Souls are naturally of different level of bliss so there is a hierarchy in Moksha also. But this doesn't need karma

Comment: @PrasannaR also Jiva experience different levels of bliss based on Sadhana??? No no Jiva experiences different levels of bliss because of it's own swaroopa. Jeeva Swaroopa is different from each other hence there is difference moksha bliss.

Comment: @GreenGold you are right karma cannot be stored in jiva swaroopa yes jiva have inherently possess bliss no need for sadhana my understanding of different levels of bliss based on karma is wrong

Comment: As per above statements then there is no need for people to do karma after atma shaakasthkara but that is not the case in madhva yathi parampara they have or had performed rigorous sadhana even after saksathkara e.g. Jayatheerth, Vyasa theertha, Vadhiraja, Vijeendira theertha and Raghavendra swamigal have all attained attained sakshathkara and performed sadhanq afterwards also

Answer (score 2):

The closest reference that I can find to this question is from *[Vachanamrut](https://www.anirdesh.com/vachanamrut/index.php?format=en&vachno=206)*.  In Vadatal prakaran, Lord Swaminarayan answering to sadhu’s question says

> The two types of bodies, sthul and sukshma, are both intimately associated with the kāran body in the same way that a tree is intimately associated with its seed. That is why it is called the kāran body. This kāran body is a form of avidyā; it is without a beginning; and it retains its sanchit karmas.

So there are definitely scriptural basis to the karma retained/stored in Sukshma and karan shareer.

In case anyone not aware, Swaminarayan followed the Vishishtadvait philosophy of Ramanujacharya and frequently quoted verses and references from Upanishads (although not specifically mentioned in this chapter “)

——————

Here are some more references to related topic. It provides scripture reference about “information on residual karma karma associated with jiva (carry/retain/store for the lack of better word)

From Āpastamba-Dharmasūtra, 2-2-3

> Then, on returning to this world, he obtains, by virtue of the **remainder of merit**, birth in a distinguished family.........

Above verse tells that there **Exists Information** (stored or retained) on residual karma (like Sanchit) and which is related to Jiva returning to this world (which may be in Jiva in sukshma or karana shareer)

(More reference to residual karma associated to jiva are in Shankaracharya commentary [here on Taittireya Upanisha](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-taittiriya-upanishad/d/doc79769.html#note-t-44717)d

Please also see [chapter on Brahmvidya](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-taittiriya-upanishad/d/doc79832.html)

(I have been researching on same topic so I wanted to share my notes. Everyone is welcome to edit the answer)

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of Karmas: Sanchita, Prarabdha and Vartaman. Sanchita Karma is all the Karma done in previous births. Prarabdha Karma is part of the Sanchita Karma that is ripe and is going to yield fruit in this birth. The Vartaman Karma is the Karma that we do in this birth.

> Vyāsa said — O King! Hear, then the causes that are certainly very wonderful. **The seers say that Karma is of three kinds — Sañchita (accumulated), Vartamāna (present) and Prārabdha (commenced).** Each of these is again subdivided into three, Sāttvik, Rājasik, and Tāmasik. **The accumulated effects of Karmas done in many past lives is called Sañchita**, O King! The effects of this Sānchita Karma, be it auspicious or inauspicious, be it for a long or for a short time, must have to be enjoyed by the beings whether they be good or bad. This Sañchita Karma done by the embodied beings in several previous births, can never be totally exhausted even in hundred Koti Kalpas without their being enjoyed. **The Karma that is being done by a Jīva and that has not as yet been completed, that is called Vartamāna Karma**. The Jīvas do this Vartamāna Karma, auspicious or inauspicious, in their present embodiments. **At the time of birth, a part of the Sañchita Karma, the soul takes up for fructification. This part of Sañchita Karma is called Prārabdha Karma**. - *Srimad Devi Bhagavatam 6.10.6-29*

It is the Prarabdha Karma that gets attached to the Linga Deha (subtle body).

> At the expiry of the above period in Heaven or Hell, when there comes the time of his assuming another body, **the Jīva becomes conscious of the subtle body (Linga Deha) and takes his birth again. When the Linga Deha comes into existence, the part of the Karma done in various previous births that are ripe and ready to yield their fruits, gets attached to the Jīva by God (or Destiny).** - *Srimad Devi Bhagavatam 4.21.24-25*

References -

[Srimad Devi Bhagavatam translated by Swami Vijnanananda](https://saraswat-prakashan.weebly.com/srimad-devi-bhagavatam.html)